# Line spacing after newcommand usage

Tags: macros, templates

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\newcounter{question}
\setcounter{question}{0}

\newcommand\Q{
\par
\stepcounter{question}
\textbf{\thequestion.}
}


\section{Definitions}

\section{Questions and answers}

\subsection{25 February 2019}


\Q  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum


answer

\Q  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

asas

\Q  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullamco laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Duis aute irure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

asas

\end{document}
```

After the first `\Q` command usage, the following questions will create a spacing. How can align all the questions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion to @campa's suggestion

```
\newcommand\Q{% <-- not necessary but doesn't hurt
  \refstepcounter{question}% <-- this IS necessary
  \paragraph{\thequestion.}
}
```

It will add some space above, and will not indent. Also added `\refstepcounter`, now you can add `\label` and refer to it.